# NSDocument based application and NSToolbar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument, nstoolbar, nspersistentdocument

I have application based on NSDocument (NSPersistentDocument), in application I can create (as usually) more than one document.

Main document window (based on NSPersistentDocument) has, added IB, toolbar. In code I add to toolbar item (NSToolbarItems) using methods `insertItemWithItemIdentifier` and `- (NSToolbarItem *)toolbar:(NSToolbar *)toolbar itemForItemIdentifier:(NSString *)itemIdentifier willBeInsertedIntoToolbar:(BOOL)flag`.

Code samples:

```
[_toolbar insertItemWithItemIdentifier:@"addTape" atIndex:2];
```

and

```
- (NSToolbarItem *)toolbar:(NSToolbar *)toolbar itemForItemIdentifier:(NSString *)itemIdentifier willBeInsertedIntoToolbar:(BOOL)flag {
    NSToolbarItem *item =nil;

    if ([itemIdentifier isEqual:@"addTape"]) {
        item = [[NSToolbarItem alloc] initWithItemIdentifier: itemIdentifier];
        item.label = NSLocalizedString(@"Add Tape",@"Add Tape");
        item.paletteLabel = NSLocalizedString(@"Add Tape",@"Add Tape");
        item.toolTip = NSLocalizedString(@"Adds new tape",@"Adds new tape");
        item.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"NSAddTemplate"];
        item.target = self;
        item.action = @selector(addTape:);
        item.tag = 101;         
    }
}
```

Everything is correct until I have opened only one document. When I open second document (or create new document) on first document window toolbar items are doubled (after opening third document, items are tripled on first window and doubled on second, and so on).

Edit: I noticed, that `itemForItemIdentifier` is called on each window, everytime I try to add toolbar item.  In example: if I have two windows (two opened document) and on one I try to add one button `itemForItemIdentifier` is called two times.
It is strange to me, because every document has own toolbar with delegate set only to this document.

I don't have any idea what I have done wrong. Maybe someone will point me where I made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution: I cannot use tooolbar created from nib, because each created this method toolbar has this same identifier. When I created toolbars in code, using different identifiers, the problem has gone.

Answer (score 1):

You don't typically insert toolbar items yourself; implement the delegate methods `toolbarAllowedItemIdentifiers:` and `toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers:` and the toolbar will be initialized according to those lists.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it's not option for me, I have to control toolbar items. But I found solution.

Comment: I ended up using the above solution.  I allow plugins to add toolbar items.  To allow this I kept a singleton which remembered the nstoolbaritems I had added (and which was the return value for the delegate methods) so insertItemWithItemIdentifier only gets called once for each new tool bar item, and and the delegate methods in each document return the same list of identifiers.  It seems that the toolbar:itemForItemIdentifier delegate method results in a copy of the item being added to the toolbar, so you can set the action and target for the correct document here, and it won't override others